# How to use powershell in remote runspace to manage Exchange

Tags: c#, powershell, office365, powershell-remoting

My boss ask me to build a web interface to allow some one to reset email box password in Exchange Online.
The only way to get all informations (Role, mail, reset password, etc...) I found is via PowerShell. So I try to run powershell inside ASP.Net. Simple batch are simple but when I try to connect at Exchange, all fail.

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://ps.outlook.com/powershell"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", Credential);
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 2;
connectionInfo.ProxyAccessType = System.Management.Automation.Remoting.ProxyAccessType.IEConfig;
connectionInfo.ProxyAuthentication = AuthenticationMechanism.Digest;
connectionInfo.ProxyCredential = ProxyCredential;
runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();
```

Credential are like *new PSCredential("admin@company.onmicrosoft.com", Securite.convertToSecureString("password"))* and ProxyCredential are like *new PSCredential("userAccount", Securite.convertToSecureString("password"))* because it's a LDAP account and I don't know if a domain is setted.

*runspace.open()* throws a System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException with this message

```
La connexion au serveur distant a échoué avec le message d'erreur suivant : Accès refusé. Pour plus d'informations, voir la rubrique d'aide about_Remote_Troubleshooting.
```

wich will be translated by

```
remote server connexion has failed with this error message : Access Denied. For more informations, go to about_Remote_Troubleshooting.
```

but were is "about_Remote_Troubleshooting" ?

So, my question is what am I doing wrong ? and What can I do to fix it ?

Thank for your attention, sorry for my english and thank you in advance for yours answers ;o)

---

Edit:
I try to rewrite my code to use PSSession

```
powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
powershell.AddParameter("Name", "cred");
powershell.AddParameter("Value", Credential);
powershell.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "RemoteSigned");
powershell.AddCommand("Enable-PSRemoting").AddParameter("Force");
powershell.AddScript("$proxysettings = New-PSSessionOption -ProxyAccessType IEConfig");
powershell.AddScript("$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 'https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/' -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -SessionOption $proxysettings");
powershell.AddScript("Import-PSSession $session");
powershell.AddScript("Get-RoleGroup | Where-Object {$_.Members -EQ 'w.user'} | Select -Property Name  | Format-List | out-string");
Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
if (powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
{
    String error = String.Empty;
    foreach (ErrorRecord _error in powershell.Streams.Error)
    {
        error += _error.Exception.Message + "\r\n";
    }
    throw new Exception(error);
}
```

It's ugly but I try having a working code before clean it.
I retrieve this errors message

```
La connexion au serveur distant a échoué avec le message d'erreur suivant : Accès refusé. Pour plus d'informations, voir la rubrique d'aide about_Remote_Troubleshooting.
Impossible de valider l'argument sur le paramètre « Session ». L'argument est null. Indiquez un argument non-null et réessayez.
Le terme « Get-RoleGroup » n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande, fonction, fichier de script ou programme exécutable. Vérifiez l'orthographe du nom, ou si un chemin d'accès existe, vérifiez que le chemin d'accès est correct et réessayez.
```

Translated :

```
Access denied : read about_Remote_Troubleshooting.
Invalid parameter "Session". Parameter is null.
"Get-RoleGroup" is not a cmdlet, function, script or executable. Check the orthographe...
```

I'm cursed /o\

Comment: about_remote_troubleshooting is a powershell commandlet, I'd wager.  Oh, look, internets:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847850.aspx

Comment: You need to use a remote PSSession, not a runspace.

Comment: do you enable the remote shell access for that user? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984292(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: thank for this answers. remote shell is enabled for this user. I rewrite the code but still doesn't work ;o)

Comment: Try using Kerberos authentication. I don't think those remote Exchange management sessions allow Basic authentication by default.

Comment: the scripts works in powershell console. Exchange online allow basic authentication.

Comment: @Zragg check if the service which runs the powershell script is running under local system account.

Comment: @Matt, sory for delay but what and how ? Now, I just try on Visual Studio with Local IIS to debug. IISExpress is launched with my account. In the futur, we 'll use a special account but I rather fight bugs, one by one ;o)

Comment: @Zragg in the control panel->services, check the properties of the service

Comment: @Matt, I confirm IISExpress isn't a service but just a process which was launched by debugger tools and this process was run with my credential.